# Ayuda con ejercicio de concatenación en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Veamos si se entiende, vamos a adelantar el tiempo dos años (**AGREGAR 2 A LA EDAD**): Declará y asigná tres variables, una con tu nombre, otra con tu apellido y otra con tu edad. Luego en la variable resultado forma la siguiente oración usando variables: “Pasado el tiempo, Juana Manso va a tener XX”.

Nombre Juana
Apellido Manso
Edad **32**

Repuesta correcta: Pasado el tiempo, Juana Manso va a tener **34**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Escribir nombre Leer nom Escribir Edad Leer edad Escribir "mi nombre es:,nom Escribir "mi edad es:",edad Escribir "Pasando el tiempo mi edad es" ,(edad+2) **Ya te di una idea ahora usa tu logica**

Comment: Hola, no puedo conseguir la variante resultado, realice todo bien, pero en el resultado la edad debe ser 34 y no 32, por eso marque en negrita esos datos.

Comment: agregue una imagen, eso es lo que voy haciendo, pero el resultado de la edad debe ser 34 y no 32.

Comment: Por otra parte es un ejercicio fácilisimo ademas esta plataforma no ayuda en tareas, si no errores sugestiones o ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema:

> únicamente estas concatenando el valor actual de `edad` pero no veo que le sumes la edad, para mostrar el valor futuro

Necesitas:

- Pedir los valores y asignarlos a 2 variables
- Declarar una nueva variable donde almacenarás la suma de la edad actual mas los dos años en el futuro
- A la variable que contiene la edad actual pasala por la función `parseInt()` para leerla como un número **y de este modo lograr que los valores se sumen**
- Con ayuda de `template strings` concatena tanto el texto como el resultado de la suma con la sintaxis de las backticks ``
- Para interpolar las variables dentro de tu *template string* usa esta sintaxis `${nombreVariable}`

Código:

```js
    let nombre = prompt("Escribe tu nombre")
    let edad   = prompt("Escribe tu edad")
    
    let edadFutura = parseInt(edad) + 2
    
    console.log(`Pasado el tiempo: ${nombre} va a tener ${edadFutura} años`)
```

O apegandonos enteramente a la sintaxis que parece exigir esa plataforma, te esta faltando envolver la suma de la edad + 2 de la sintaxis de concatenación así:

```js
    var nombre = "Juana"
    var apellido = "Manso"
    var edad = 32
    
    var resultado = "Pasado el tiempo, "+nombre+" "+apellido+" "+"va a tener "+(edad + 2)
    console.log(resultado)
```

Comment: sii! pensaba agregar una nueva variante donde almacene esos 2 años futuros, pero en el ejercicio solo me pide agregar 4 variales (nombre, apellido,edad y resultado) Por eso estoy confundido. Entiendo que hay varias formas de resolverlo, pero debo resolver el ejercicio con lo que he aprendido hasta el momento.

Comment: @JuanManuelTavano acabo de editar mi respuesta mas apegado a tu ejercicio mira y dime

Comment: esta correctisima!!! si te tuviese al lado te abrazaria!!!! muchas gracias por tu tiempo, valoro mucho tu ayuda.

Comment: echo!! gracias infinitas =)